# Converting input hex 0A to \n escaped character

Tags: python, serial-port, hex, escaping, html-escape-characters

I am using webpage to get data in hex to write serial modbus using python

Issue is that `0A` in the string gets converted to `\n`.

How to stop this from happening?

```
rList = r'0106000600000AE9CC'
arr=str(rList)
arr = bytes.fromhex(rList)

print(arr)
```

Output:

```
b'\x01\x06\x00\x06\x00\x00\n\xe9\xcc'
```

Comment: The hex value of the character _is_ `0A`, Python is just displaying it as an escape character when displaying the byte string's representation.

Answer (score 1):

The repr() representation of a bytes object uses ASCII code points wherever possible.
What this means is `\x0A` will be displayed as `\n`, because that's the ASCII code point for a newline.

More examples:
`\x55` will be displayed as `U`, 
`\x5A` will be displayed as `Z`, 
`\x0D` will be displayed as `\r`,
 you get the idea.

However, the data under the hood is still the same.

Don't worry about how the output string is displayed by the Python console—it's presumably more important to process its content.

Comment: issue is that i have to send command to modbus 
and it take commands like this: \x01\x06\x00\x06\x0a\xe9\xcc
but what python sends is this: \x01\x06\x00\x06\\n\xe9\xcc

Comment: I don't think that's true, the underlying data is as-is, untouched. If the data is `\x01\x06\x00\x06\x0a\xe9\xcc`, then what is SENT is `\x01\x06\x00\x06\x0a\xe9\xcc` and what is DISPLAYED on console is `\x01\x06\x00\x06\\n\xe9\xcc`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def print_me(thing: bytes):
    print(''.join(
        f'\\x{byte:02x}'
        for byte in thing
    ))
print_me(bytes.fromhex("0106000600000AE9CC"))
```

Output:

```
\x01\x06\x00\x06\x00\x00\x0a\xe9\xcc
```

Answer (score 0):

`b` symbol before string means you have a list of bytes. As you print it, python tries to decode bytes whenever possible to represent them in symbols for simplicity.

Byte `b'\x0A'` corresponds to decimal value 10, which is a [newline symbol in ascii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). That is why you get this symbol printed.

Under the hood your byte `b'\x0A'` has not been changed.